# how to return a table td tags in array?

Tags: php, html, arrays

i have a table like this in a string:

```
<table>
    <tr class='test'>
        <td class='t' style='color: red'>
            aaaaa
        </td>
        <td class='t'>
            bbbbb
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style='color: red'>
            ccccc
        </td>
        <td class='t'>
            ddddd
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

now how i can put all td contents in an array in PHP?
like this:

```
array(
      arg[0] => 'aaaaa',
      arg[1] => 'bbbbb',
      arg[2] => 'ccccc',
      arg[3] => 'ddddd',
)
```

Comment: The first thing I would do when faced with this problem is try *something*.

Comment: You need parse XML, look for SimpleXML. And don't try to parse HTML by regulars.

Comment: ohk, sorry for my bad answer. I didn't notice that the table was in a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to parse the HTML, and get the elements.

```
$result = array();

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($table);
$xPath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$td = $xPath->query('//table/tr/td');

foreach($td as $val){
    $result[] = $val->nodeValue;
}

print_r($result);
```

DEMO: http://codepad.viper-7.com/wqIPbp

Comment: @Dyin: `DOMDocument` is pretty awesome :-)

Comment: Yeah. Actually I was thinking in a regular expression from the first time. It's nice to have a library like this in mind. :P

Comment: very nice. thanks dear @Rocket. i enjoyed  very very very much :*

Comment: @Dyin: Regular expressions are *not* for XML/HTML.  PHP also has [`SimpleXML`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php), which can parse XML.